# JavaScript getElementByID() for HTML Table

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

Learning Javascript at the moment, so please bear with me. I created a table in my connected.html and I am trying to obtain the element between the `<td>` tags in my event-page.js. I used `document.getElementByID("tokens")`, however I get *null*, I want to get 12. I think I have to do more with `document.getElementByID("tokens")` I used `.innerText` and `.innerHTML` but those didn't work. Any help would be appreciated! Sorry for such a simple problem.

*Note: The function in event-page.js is called when a button is clicked by the user.

connected.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="info">Tokens</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="tokens">12</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

event-page.js

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if (request.action.split(':')[0] === 'got-it'){

        yt_name = (request.action.split(':')[1])

        console.log(yt_name)

        let table = document.getElementById("tokens")

        console.log(table)
    }
})
```

Comment: have you link the JS file in html page ?

Comment: I this a content script?  https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts Please provide a more complete example. At this point it's unclear how the HTML document and the JavaScript file are wired together.

Comment: @VLAZ I saw that! I couldn't find a reference in `.getElementById()` with a table though...

Comment: @FelixKling event-page.js is a background script

Comment: Background scripts cannot access the DOM of the web page afaik. You need a content script that accesses the DOM and communicates with your background script. This has nothing to do with how JavaScript or the DOM works but with how Chrome extensions work.

Comment: @FerinPatel I did not link the event-page.js in html page...if I am suppose to how would I approach that?

Comment: @FelixKling Oh yikes, I know that rule! However, connected.html is an .html I created for the user to view, so the event-page.js still can't access the DOM?

Comment: Then how your event-page.js is able access the DOM ???

Comment: @FerinPatel Wait...in the connected.html do I need to include     `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/event-page.js"></script>` , if I do, event-page.js should be able to identify the element?

Comment: yes, by doing so you can access the token id from DOM

Comment: Wait, so `connected.html` is supposed to be rendered as part of the Chrome extension? As I said before, please provide more context. We cannot know how all these files are related.

Comment: @FerinPatel I added that one line into connected.html however, still *null*

Comment: @FelixKling Very sorry, not sure how well I can explain it through text. The way it is structured is that there is a popup.html. When a button is pressed in the popup.html, it then executes `chrome.browserAction.setPopup({ popup: "connected.html" })`  , by executing that API, it will add a new popup .html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Works, that means your EventListener are called before the DOM is loaded.

```js
let table = document.getElementById("tokens")
console.log(table)
```

```html
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="info">Tokens</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="tokens">12</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: That makes sense, I think I need to check the structure of my program. Thank you!